# PHP for catching POST value

Tags: php

How can I catch POST value using PHP for the parameter with multiple third bracket?
Ex.

```
content[fields][attendees]
content[fields][completed]
```

Okay, let me post url encoded raw data here:

```
type=activities.update&objectid=75585970&content%5Bid%5D=75585970&content%5Bname%5D=Order+Received%2F+Processing+request+%28may+need+more+info%29&content%5Bcreated%5D=2013-03-15T16%3A09%3A50%2B00%3A00&content%5Bupdated%5D=2013-03-16T06%3A37%3A01%2B00%3A00&content%5Bviewed%5D=2013-03-16T06%3A35%3A21%2B00%3A00&content%5Blevel%5D=1&content%5Bflagged%5D=0&content%5Btypeid%5D=22&content%5Bparenttypeid%5D=2&content%5Bparent%5D=75585967&content%5Bparentname%5D=Tanmoy+Sadhu+%7C+weew+%7C+RSA&content%5Bitem%5D=75585967&content%5Bitemname%5D=Tanmoy+Sadhu+%7C+weew+%7C+RSA&content%5Bitemtypeid%5D=2&content%5Bposition%5D=2&content%5Bfields%5D%5Battendees%5D=&content%5Bfields%5D%5Bcompleted%5D=1&content%5Bfields%5D%5Btitle%5D=Order+Received%2F+Processing+request+%28may+need+more+info%29+
```

I've tried with `$_POST['content[fields][attendees]']` and `$_POST['content\[fields\]\[attendees\]']` but no luck.

Any way to catch that?

Comment: and what does either `var_dump($_POST);` or `echo "<pre>". print_r($_POST, true) ."</pre>";` show?

Comment: firstly post `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I believe the correct syntax would be `$_POST['content']['field']` etc so for the example of `&content%5Bid%5D=75585970` you can get the value 75585970 by calling $_POST['content']['id'];

Comment: @Stegrex, please post your comment as answer so that I can accept that. You solved my issue. You should be voted.

Comment: @NoviceCoder Thanks, I appreciate it! I'm just glad that I was able to help you solve what you were trying to find. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax would be

`$_POST['content']['field']` etc

so for the example of `&content%5Bid%5D=75585970` you can get the value `75585970` by calling

`$_POST['content']['id'];`

This is because the $_POST value for any particular key is a string (or array in the case the key has brackets).

In this case, `$_POST['content']` returns an array of many different key value pairs, and you can access the values using those array keys just like in any multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo $_POST['content']['id'];
echo $_POST['content']['name'];
echo $_POST['content']['fields']['attendees'];
```

etc.

Output from your url parameters:

```
75585970
Order Received/ Processing request (may need more info)
<-empty string here for attendees
```